# Running Jasmine tests in Typescript, with Chutzpah

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, jasmine, chutzpah

I am trying to figure out how typescript-jasmine-chutzpah combination will finally test my typescript code. So I have a sample project (shown in the picture).

[image]

I have an app.ts file with the following content

```
class Calculator {
    add = function(x:number, y:number) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

and the test file appTest.ts

```
/// <reference path="../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../app.ts" />

/// <chutzpah_reference path="../jasmine/jasmine.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../../app.js" />

describe("Test Calc", function () {

    it("add function", function () {
        var calc = new Calculator(),
            res = calc.add(4, 7);
        expect(res).toBe(11);
    });
});
```

If I run tests on testApp.ts the output will be "0 passed, 0 failed, 0 total (chutzpah)." but if I run the compiled testApp.js it seems to work fine "1 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (chutzpah)."

1) Why the tests in .ts file are not found?
2) Should I test my typescript code writing code in Typescript or directly with JavaScript?

Can someone help me figure out this simple test set up and make it work?
Notice that I don't use chutzpah.json at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was reading the docs (or some other articles), it was clearthat chutzpah.json was optional for a simple test to run, but the only way to make it work, was to add chutzpah.json at the root of the project with the following content:

```
{
  "Framework": "jasmine",

  "References": [
    { "Path": "app.js" },
    { "Path": "scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js" }
  ],

  "Tests": [
    { "Path": "scripts/tests/apptest.js" }
  ]
}
```

So, for any future reference, chutzpah.json is **required** in order chutzpah to run the tests. Also, note that the "chutzpah_reference"s are not needed anymore in the test file.

Comment: It was optional in the past but as of version 3 it has been required.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use a chutzpah.json file it will not work. Please [follow this](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/Compilation/ExternalCompile) example to see how to make it work properly.

Comment: I found that out the hard way. Please make that clear in the docs. Thank you a lot for your trouble :)